# How to configure c3po+hibernate to fail all requests in a specified interval until database is back up?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jdbc, c3p0

I am trying to application db (Mysql) fail proof. I have successfully reached a stage where in case of any form of network outage, my db layer will throw an exception. Now I am stuck at how to re-attempt connections once the database is back up. I am using c3po as my connection pool manager. I have set the `breakAfterAcquireFailure = true` since I want to disable db calls in case of failures. However, when the database is back up, the connection acquiring attempts still fail due to this property(as expected). Is there any other configuration parameter which can override this after a certain interval?

I know that I can always write a mechanism to poll the db periodically, but wanted to know if there's a configuration support for this.

Thanks

Comment: the point of the default `breakAfterAcquireFailure = false` is that, once the DB goes down, it can still com back up again. i don't think you want that setting. have you configured just leaving `breakAfterAcquireFailure = false`and just setting `testConnectionOnCheckout` to true?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As per my understanding, testConnectionOnCheckout will attempt to verify connection every time a new request comes even if the db is down. This is similar to not setting any of these properties, except for the verification part. In that case c3po attempts for a connection in case of a new request, it'll give timeouts an each request, and when the database is back up, it'll reconnect.
In my case, I want all db calls to fail after the first failure, until a specified time. I am afraid testConnectionOnCheckout won't help here, assuming I understood it correctly.

Comment: there's no way in c3p0 to configure something like "break for a specified time". but usually what you want is "break until the database comes back up", which is what c3p0 tries to do. i guess your issue is that you want client Connections to fail immediately, rather than wait, when the database is down.

Comment: one way to almost do this would be to set a short `checkoutTimeout`. the problem with that is that, if it is very short, some clients may timeout even when the database is up, just because Connections are in use. however, if you make the pool size large relative to the volume of requests you expect, you may be able to configure a short `checkoutTimeout` with only very rare spurious failures (as the oversize pool means there are almost always Connections available to check out).

Comment: Hey thanks for your comment. I've tried setting a short checkoutTimeout and it seems to work in some cases. However, the cases it doesn't work is when the mysql port is blocked. In that case, the connection attempt just seems to take forever. I eventually settled on using connectTimeout and socketTimeout offered by JDBC. So in the end, I've set these timeouts really short ((but above the expected delays) , like you suggested for checkoutTimeout  and it's working fine.

Comment: sounds good! the only thing you can use at the c3p0 level for situations in which attempts to connect neither succeed nor fail but hang indefinitely is [maxAdministrativeTaskTime](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#maxAdministrativeTaskTime). but that's a pretty ugly failsafe, and it sounds like you've found a configuration that is working for you.